# Store vectors that result form for loop and then compute the average of all these vectors

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, matrix, indexing

I have a 4 by 4 matrix:

```
A=[rand(1) 2 -1 rand(1);  
   rand(1) 3 rand(1) 0;  
   rand(1) -5 -2 5;  
   9  0   0 rand(1)];
```

Now I would like to form a vector b to be the first column of the matrix `A`. So the vector `b` is

```
b=[rand(1)  
   rand(1)  
   rand(1)  
   9 ];
```

I would like to write a for loop that compute b many times say 100 then store these vectors in matrix `C` ( which now has size of 4*100) and then compute the mean of all columns of `C`. So far I wrote:

```
for j=1:100
   A=[rand(1) 2 -1 rand(1);...
      rand(1) 3 rand(1) 0;...
      rand(1) -5 -2 5;...
      9 0 0 rand(1)];
   b=A(:,1)
end
```

Every time the loop executed, it produces a vector, say `b_1` then `b_2,....,b_100`. How to store them in matrix `C=[b_1 b_2 ... b_100]` and then compute the mean of matrix `C` over all columns so that the mean will be a vector of size 4 by 1 the same size as `b`.

Comment: try to use the code in the answer and let us know if it works as you want so we can try to fix other problem if there are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Matlab on this laptop but the little script should be like this:

```
for jj=1:100
C(:,jj)=[rand(1) ;...
  rand(1) ;...
  rand(1) ;...
  9 ];
end
```

The matrix C will contain all the column-vectors b. To access to any of them just use `b(:,x)` where `x` is the index-number or column that you want to use.
For the average you can do something like this:

```
b_average=[mean(C(1,:)); mean(C(2,:)); mean(C(3,:));mean(C(4,:))];
```

Of course the last mean upon a vector with only `9` values hasn't meaning: I leave the code as it is just for completeness.
Remember as well that the average of a vector with random numbers will be really close to the value zero if `N` is big enough (where N is the number of the sample in the vector of course).

Anyway, the for loop is not the best way to do this. Try to use something like this:

```
C=[rand(1,100);rand(1,100);rand(1,100);9*ones(1,100)];
```

or better (as it was point out by Adriaan)

```
C=[rand(3,100);9*ones(1,100)];
```

This line does the same of the for loop. Again: try to don't use the variable `j` and `i`in Matlab because they are reserved.

Comment: Thank you.  It really works fine and it is a complete answer.

Comment: I am glad of this! if you like the answer and if you find it helpful you can also vote up! I will really appreciate